# Find $f$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)+\cdots$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

A function $f(x)$ satisfies the condition,$f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)+f''''(x)+......\infty$,where $f(x)$ is a differentiable function indefinitely and dash denotes the order of the derivative.If $f(0)=1$,then find the function $f(x).$

---

$f(x)=f'(x)+f''(x)+f'''(x)+f''''(x)+......\infty$
$f'(x)=f''(x)+f'''(x)+f''''(x)+......\infty$
$f''(x)=f'''(x)+f''''(x)+......\infty$
But i do not know how to solve it further.I am stuck here.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: We have absolute convergence? So $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f^{(i)}(x)$ uniformly on which domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x)$, differentiating it again, we obtain
$$f'(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f^{(k+1)}(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(x) = f(x) - f'(x)$$
This means $f'(x) = \dfrac{f(x)}2 \implies f(x) = C\exp(x/2)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You will have a differential equation. $f(x)-f'(x)=???$.

Answer (score 2):

f is two times its derivative from the first two relations (just subtract), so you get exp(x/2) up to a multiplicative constant

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x) - f'(x) = f'(x)$ in case of absolute convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}
$$
for $0<\alpha<1,$ one might guess that
$$
f(x)=Ce^{\alpha x}.
$$
Since $f(0)=1$, we need $C = 1$ and substituting $f(x)=e^{\alpha x}$ into $$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x)
$$
we have
$$
e^{\alpha x} = (\alpha + \alpha^2 + \ldots )e^{\alpha x}
$$
and hence
$$
1=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}
$$
yielding $\alpha=2$.
Therefore
$$
f(x)=e^{x/2}.
$$