# Find $f$ s. t. $\sum f^{(n)}(x) = f(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem :**

Find function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x) = f(x)$$

where $f^{(n)}(x)$ denotes $\displaystyle\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$

---

I think the solution is : $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = \exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

At first I tried with $f(x) = \exp(kx)$

Then we know that $f^{(n)}(x)=k^n\exp(kx)$

So,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^{(n)}(x) = f(x) \quad\Rightarrow\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty k^n=1$$

And we know $k=\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally I got $f(x)=\exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

And the zero function also satisfies this equation.

But How can I verify there is no more solution?

Comment: Trying with the more general ansatz $f(x) = c \exp(k x)$ shows that $c \exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ is also a solution for all $c \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: In the case of second order, if you have only one root, then you write down two solutions $e^{kx}$ and $xe^{kx}$ as your two independent solutions. So check that $f(x) = x^k e^{x/2}$ are solutions.

Comment: @TravisWillse, It's a linear equation so scaling solutions just give another solution. Check for constants $c\in\mathbb{R}$ give no additional information.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1570831/42969

Comment: @DogeChan Yes, but OP's phrasing suggested that they hadn't yet made that observation.